# Boostrap container overflow and not responsive (always displayed two columns)

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I have created a form with two columns. But when I decrease the browser width, two columns are preserved even when their content overflows. I have tried to change the code to plain DIV with container class, specify cols count, set width but it resists.

Here is the codepen: https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-goldberg-4ugt6

and the source code of the parent container:

```
<div class="container flex-wrap pt-3 w-75 ml-auto mr-auto mt-auto mb-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <b-card>
        <SeriesForm />
      </b-card>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <b-card :header="captions[1]">
        <SeriesForm :group="forms[1]" />
      </b-card>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col text-center p-4">
      <b-button>Analyse</b-button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I make it two columns when there is enough space and single column otherwise?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue isn't with the bootstrap grid itself, the issue is with how your checkboxes are displayed.

You're defining in the `.align-nicely` class, that your checkbox group must always be 3 columns.
`display: grid` isn't that smart. So if you tell it to be 3 columns, it will be 3 columns and ignore everything else. This is why your content is overflowing.

So to fix the issue or improve it at least. You have to change how the `display: grid` columns are handled.

One method would be to use CSS `@media` queries, to define how many columns there should be at a given screen width. This way you can scale them down as the screen gets smaller.

The below CSS should work if you use `<b-col xl='6'>` with your current text.

```css
.align-nicely {
  display: grid;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1350px) {
  .align-nicely {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 576px) {
  .align-nicely {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}
```

Another solution could be to use the `repeat()` function combined with `minmax()`.
This option will be a lot more dynamic than the first one, but will break the alignment across your different groups.

```css
.align-nicely {
  display: grid;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
  /* 
    The 110px inside minmax(), is how small each column is allowed to get.
    So if there isn't space on the current row for the column to be over 110px, 
    it will be moved to a new row. So you will need to adjust this based on your content size.
  */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(110px, 1fr));
}
```

Comment: This fixes the content  of the form box, thank you. But if I shrink the window too much, both boxes are still displayed besides each other.

Comment: Add `cols="12"` to your `b-col`'s

Answer (score 2):

U can try class like `col-sm-6` or `col-xs-6` or `col-md-6` or `col-lg-6` according to your need.

```
<div class="container flex-wrap pt-3 w-75 ml-auto mr-auto mt-auto mb-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <b-card>
        <SeriesForm />
      </b-card>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <b-card :header="captions[1]">
        <SeriesForm :group="forms[1]" />
      </b-card>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col text-center p-4">
      <b-button>Analyse</b-button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. There is the same trouble as with Charbel answer.  The box overflows at some width and two columns are still displayed.

Comment: I have seen your code. I would suggest you that if you can replace the radio inputs with a dropdown then it may help you somewhat. Use <b-form-select> instead of <b-form-radio>
Hopefully it will help you.

Comment: Multiselect would be option but it is harder to use from UX perspective.  And it is bad when I have just three items.

Comment: Maybe you are right, but dropdown is good when there are a lot of options. You can use radio on sex field and use dropdown in below fields.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because of the flex display,

what you need to do is set the columns with below your row for each form :

use this `<div class='col-12 col-xl-6'>` instead of `<div class='col'>` .. the spacing is a little bit tight so you might need to remove some of the margins and paddings

this will make each form take full width on big screens and below and will make them 50% width on xl screens

Comment: You did not specify where to replace the class so I replaced it everywhere. It really breaks the row to two rows on small displays. But  there is a width when two columns are displayed but their content overflows the frame.

Comment: find the class called ".align-nicely" and change its display type to block on your desired media screen, inside of this element you will have children with class ".custom-control-inline" set their width to 50% and remove the margin-right off of them. this should solve your content overflowing

Comment: you add the col class as the parent container of the element that you desire to change the width accordingly, in our case the col class should be the parent element of the card element

Comment: Can you please edit the code pen? It will be easier to read. I would nee to guess what you mean otherwise.

Comment: Your suggestion is hard for me to understand. Please update your answer or codesandbox. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have added attribute to your  tags[image: this image shows the code changed and also the form in the format you wanted.]

If you will expand the screen then u will get the initial format.

Comment: Thank you but this is just another iteration of the same concept. The boxes overflow when there are two cells side by side. Try to drag code pen panel.